# Passing 0x20, 0x00, 0x0d, 0x0a bytes to strcmp()

Tags: python, string, null, strcmp

I'm trying to do a challenge where there's a strange strcmp.
It is the following:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1],"\x00")) return 0;
if(strcmp(argv[2],"\x20\x0a\x0d")) return 0;
```

I've tried to pass the arguments through Python but the bytes aren't read in the correct way.
This is what I tried:

```
./program $(python -c 'import sys;sys.stdout.write("\x00 \x20\x0a\x0d")')
```

I also tried to use their `repr` but that didn't work too. They are currently being evaluated for what every byte actually represents: how do I "pass them as they are" correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the backslash escapes to be evaluated, you need to escape them.

This:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "\\x20\\x0a\\x0d")) return 0;
```

compares against the literal string `"\x20\x0a\x0d"`, which has 12 characters.

From a command-line perspective, the first argument should be an empty string (typically written as `""` in most shells), and the second should be the tree-character string `" \n\r"` in Python notation.

Not sure what Python has to do with things here, from e.g. bash you should be able to do:

```
$ ./program "" $'\n\r'
```

Comment: I can't edit the challenge code so I HAVE to evaluate against "\x20\x0a\x0d"